# PHP DOM Get website all scripts src

Tags: javascript, php, dom, preg-match

I am want to get all scripts src links from a website using curl and DOM.

I have this code:

```
$scripts = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script');

foreach ($scripts as $scripts1) {

    if($scripts1->getAttribute('src')) {

        echo $scripts1->getAttribute('src');

    }

}
```

This script working perfeclty but what happens if a website has a script tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window._wpemojiSettings = {"source":{"concatemoji":"http:\/\/domain.com\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.2.4"}}; ........
</script>
```

I need also to get this script src. How can I do that?

Comment: Then you need to write some code to find that other mechanism for including scripts

Comment: That `<script>` tag doesn't have an `src` attribute.  It's some inline JavaScript that sets the variable `_wpemojiSettings` to an object.

Comment: I know is not have, this is the reason why I am asking, because some has, other not have, but use an object to load the src. If you guys can give me an ideea from where to start.

Comment: Maybe take a look at `WWW:Mechanize` to execute Javascript.

Comment: There are countless ways to embed the URL of a script file into JavaScript code and dynamically load it.  You'd need to somehow parse/execute the JavaScript code and figure out where the URL is stored.

Comment: But if I use a preg_match to search for .js inside the script tag and next to retrieve the whole link that have the ".js" inside, in this case to retrieve the link inside the " ".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you first parser comes empty, I'd create another using a regex, i.e.:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://somesite.com/");

preg_match_all('/<script.*?(http.*?\.js(?:\?.*?)?)"/si', $html, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) {
    echo str_replace("\\/", "/", $matches[1][$i]);
}
```

---

You may have to adjust the regex to work with different websites but the above code should give you an idea of what you need.

---

DEMO:
http://ideone.com/Fwf6Mb

---

Regex Explanation:

```
<script.*?(http.*?\.js(?:\?.*?)?)"
----------------------------------

Match the character string “<script” literally «<script»
Match any single character «.*?»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(http.*?\.js(?:\?.*?)?)»
   Match the character string “http” literally «http»
   Match any single character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
   Match the character “.” literally «\.»
   Match the character string “js” literally «js»
   Match the regular expression below «(?:\?.*?)?»
      Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
      Match the character “?” literally «\?»
      Match any single character «.*?»
         Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “"” literally «"»
```

---

Regex Tutorial

http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you for your code, it's working but it gets all type of links (images etc) from script tag. I need only the .js files. Something like if I do a preg_match to get only links that have .js inside.

Comment: Working like a charm, and also need to add the version for .js?ver=x.x.x , I tried this but not working '/<script.*?(http.*?\.js?ver=)"/si' . Thanks

Comment: Just add `.*?` after `js`

Comment: Now gives me same result + 1 new link that not have js

Comment: I'm on mobile, I'll update the regex when I'm at home.

Comment: Check it out @GeorgePredus.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider vote 1+ and accepting it as the correct answer by clicking the check mark in the middle of the vote arrows, tks !

Comment: Thank you very much, you really helped me. I marked your answer as correct. But please can you check again the code, seems not working. It gives me a .js link and also another one that is not js.

Comment: I've already helped you, no it's your turn to get your hand dirty and discover the solution by yourself, otherwise you'll never learn.